# The `auto` mode of `contain-intrinsic-height` isn't remembering discovered element heights?

Tags: html, css

In [this simple jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/zubijahiso/edit?html,output), I have code that looks like this:

```html
<style>
  div {
    content-visibility: auto;
    contain-intrinsic-height: auto 10px;
  }
</style>
<div>a<br>a<br>a</div>
<div>a<br>a<br>a</div>
<div>a<br>a<br>a</div>
...
```

I've set the height to 10px, but the actual heights of the `div`s are larger.

I'd assumed that this would mean that there is weird scrollbar resizing as the user scrolls down the page, but not when they scroll back up - since the browser has already discovered and remembered the heights of the elements that are being scrolled past on the way back up.

However, that doesn't appear to be the case. In Chrome (v100) there is scrollbar resizing on the way down and up, just as if I had not added the `auto` option.

The `auto` value is mentioned [here](https://web.dev/content-visibility/#specifying-the-natural-size-of-an-element-with-contain-intrinsic-size), and they only mention Chrome support for `contain-intrinsic-size` auto, rather than the individual `height` and `width` options, but the `size` version doesn't work either. So I assume they just mentioned `contain-intrinsic-size` as a catch-all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a Chromium bug that will be fixed in Chrome v102: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1318726#c4